# Installing JSDT jQuery plugin in Eclipse Kepler 4.3

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

I've downloaded Eclipse Kepler 4.3 from official site in [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-43/keplerr).

And installed PDT plugin successfully (`Eclipse -> Help -> Install new software`).

**The problem :**

I need to install JSDT jQuery plugin.

I have tried :

```
Help -> Eclipse MarketPlace -> JSDT jQuery (Install)
```

But get me following error :

> No repository found at
>   https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/jsdt-jquery/updatesite

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Method 1 :**

1. Run Eclipse
2. Help -> Install New Software
3. Copy [this link address](https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/jsdt-jquery/updatesite) and paste it on `Work with` section and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. After a few seconds `JSDT jQuery` checkbox will be appears.
5. Check `JSDT jQuery` and press next button and Next again..
6. Accept License Agreement and press Finish.
7. Restart Eclipse

   ---

**Method 2 :**

8. Download and install SVN client for example [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)
9. [Import the repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html#tsvn-qs-import). Paste this URL https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/jsdt-jquery/updatesite in the URL of the repository field.
10. Then hit `OK`.

After that :

1. Run Eclipse Kepler
2. Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> Archive
3. Select ZIP file that was downloaded, and type a name.
4. Click OK.
5. Select JSDT Plugin check box and hit `Next`.
6. Accept licence and press Confirm.
7. Restart Eclipse

**UPDATE**

If you are unable to download that for any reasons(*Specially for Iranian people*), you can download that from below link :

http://www.mediafire.com/download/924166rcorf4bt1/JSDT_jQuery_-_20131019.zip

*And then do above steps*

Comment: As the code spot in not currently available in IRAN, I just uploaded it here s2.picofile.com/file/7975667197/JSDT_jQuery_20131019.zip.html

Comment: How can i install it without any internet connection?

Comment: @RasoolGhafari Just download JSDT plugin from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/924166rcorf4bt1/JSDT_jQuery_-_20131019.zip) and try above steps..

Comment: The zip at mediafire contain this.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

Answer (score 6):

To anyone having issues in 2016, I took the following steps:

1. List item
2. Download source code from https://code.google.com/archive/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jsdt-jquery/source/default/source or https://github.com/Nodeclipse/jsdt-jquery
3. Unzip and maven build the source code
4. In eclipse `Help`->`Install New Software`->`Add...`->`Archive...`->`/location_to_source_directory/org.eclipselabs.jsdt.updatesite/target/org.eclipselabs.jsdt.updatesite-1.9.0-SNAPSHOT-site.zip`
5. Give name -> `Ok`
6. ...
7. Profit

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have posted a reference to this answer on this plugin's GitHub ["Issues" page](https://github.com/marschall/jsdt-jquery/issues/1#issuecomment-266417220) for other users.

Comment: Link for the required jar.
https://github.com/marschall/jsdt-jquery/files/913910/org.eclipselabs.jsdt.updatesite-1.9.0-SNAPSHOT-site.zip

Comment: @MuralidharBg Sounds like you need to open a new question.

Comment: @Nielsvh I guess so. Actually the steps I added as comments did not work for me and I gave up on trying to install it. I'm going to remove my previous comment

Comment: @vee IE build the project with maven, not literally `maven build`.

Answer (score 5):

To install JSDT jQuery plugin follow these steps:

1. Run Eclipse Kepler
2. From the top toolbar select Help -> Install New Software
3. In the box labelled *Work with:* copy and paste https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/jsdt-jquery/updatesite and hit enter.
4. Check *JSDT jQuery* and select the *Next* button
5. On the Install Details dialog select *Next*
6. Accept the License Agreement and select *Finish*
7. Select *Yes* to restart Eclipse

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use the Eclipse Marketplace, then you can also get updates for the plugin.

1. Run Eclipse
2. Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
3. Search for "jQuery"
4. Choose JSDT jQuery 1.7.0 (or newer version when it arrives)
5. Choose Install
6. Confirm selected features (check that it is selected and click Confirm)
7. Accept licence and press Confirm
8. Restart Eclipse

Comment: It's a good approach but this way doesn't work in my country Iran(It's a government issue!). All Iranian people have to do that by hand or use a Proxy.

Comment: Yes, true. So not the ideal solution for you. Can you use a proxy to reach Eclipse Marketplace?

Comment: Yes I can but I did it without proxy

Answer (score 0):

For install lastet version of JSDT Jquery plugin plesae enable a proxy in your pc and then open eclipse from toolbar select Help -> Install New Software and click the Add button and copy & paste this https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/jsdt-jquery/updatesite

Next click select all and click next to install it