# How to setup a JSDT for Eclipse Kepler 4.3?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I would like to do some JavaScript development with my Eclipse Kepler 4.3 installation.  I noticed the default JavaScript editor does not provide code completion like the normal Java Editor does.

Do I need to install a JSDT plugin to enable this?  Which do you recommend?  Any help on process to install it would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734967/installing-jsdt-jquery-plugin-in-eclipse-kepler-4-3

Answer (score 0):

If you have the pre-packaged version "Eclipse for Java EE", then it already includes JSDT: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2

If you have another version, then you will need to install the plugin from the Kepler Repository, for more info see [Installing JSDT jQuery plugin in Eclipse Kepler 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734967/installing-jsdt-jquery-plugin-in-eclipse-kepler-4-3)

Comment: Regarding how to install the plugin: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734967/installing-jsdt-jquery-plugin-in-eclipse-kepler-4-3

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't do code completion.  Is there something else I need to add to get this functionality?  Also, I cannot go directly to a function declaration or a variable declaration.  Do I need to add a third party's JSDT to get this?  I saw there were some for JQuery.    I am new to JS development, so maybe I'm not doing something correctly?

Comment: The link I copied above installs the jQuery integration, which means first you have to install jsdt and then the jQuery integration

Comment: Also, if you are going to develop for web my advice is to download the version of Eclipse called "Eclipse for Java EE" since, besides JSDT, it includes many other packages that you will find useful.